# How to Insert an Image in to an Ellipse and Hide Overflowing Parts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

I'm trying to insert an image in to an ellipse shape layer, I need to hide the overflowing parts around the circle/ellipse.

How do I insert an image in to a circular selection and hide the parts that are outside the ellipse using Photoshop?

Essentially, I want to put a normal image in to a circular object, creating a round image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Paste your image in to Photoshop. *Drag and drop or use Open dialog*
2. Create the shape layer (ellipse).
3. Make sure your image is above the shape layer in the `Layers` panel.

   [image]
4. Right click your image in the layers panel, and choose `Create Clipping Mask`.

   [image]

Et voila! A non destructive method for creating circular or elliptical images.

[image]

I know this has already been answered with a very similar answer, but I felt it wasn't descriptive enough. Screenshots make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 5):

Create ellipse shape with dimensions.
Keep image layer top of ellipse layer.
Now select image layer goto **Layer** click on **Create Clipping Mask**(Alt+Ctrl+G).
[image]

Shortcut: Select image layer hold **alt** key click between image layer and shape layer.