# Inserting an image into a shape worked before but suddenly does not

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipping-mask

There was a previous question: [How to Insert an Image in to an Ellipse and Hide Overflowing Parts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21038/how-to-insert-an-image-in-to-an-ellipse-and-hide-overflowing-parts). Dom answered the question and I was using that method successfully. However, now some setting must have been changed accidentally or something because now, using the same method, I get the picture cut out leaving an outline of it instead of placing the picture into the shape.  What setting would cause this inversion?

Answer (score 0):

Layer 1 is your shape

Layer 2 is your image (Should be directly above Layer 1)

1) Select layer 2 and press CTRL + Alt + G or CMD + Alt + G to create clipping mask.

OR

2) You can also hold alt and left click between the 2 layers.

Comment: I am using those steps and it has worked fine until recently.  When I get to the create clipping mask step it either takes the image away entirely or makes the image a border for a transparent space.  The goal is to have an image with rounded edges.

Comment: @Lisa May I am not sure what is wrong without seeing your layers panel. I doubt that changing a Photoshop preference would prevent you from doing a clipping mask but you could also reset Photoshop preferences.